# Why did the author choose to use the passive voice "I am parachuted" instead of the active voice "I parachute" in this context?

Tags: passive-voice

This paragraph is taken from an English coursebook, from a lesson called "Dangerous Jobs". The entire article is called "Smoke jumper".

> **I am parachuted** into areas where there are forest fires. Once I am there, I have to cut trees down and clear plants to stop the fire spreading. It is risky, because fire and smoke can kill you, but we wear special protective clothes to stop the heat and smoke from affecting us. If we do our job well, we have the satisfaction of saving people’s lives and protecting forests.- *"English for Starters - Students' Book" by Julia Starr Keddle & Martyn Hobbs*

Why did the author choose to use the passive voice "I am parachuted" instead of the active voice "I parachute" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The use of the present tense suggests that it is something that happens regularly.
The verb **[parachute](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parachute)** normally means to jump from an aircraft using a parachute: this meaning is intransitive, so it cannot be used in passive voice.  There is a second, transitive, meaning: to drop someone or something from an aircraft by parachute.

The use of this second meaning in passive voice suggests that somebody else makes the decision about where and when the speaker is dropped.